# Minimize dependence between vectors?

Tags: geometry, vectors

Assume two $3D$ points namely $A$ and $B$ with coordinates $A=(A_x,A_y,A_z)$ and $B=(B_x,B_y,B_z)$. Let's say that $A_x,A_y,B_x,B_y$ are distributed uniformly on a disk with radius $R$ whereas $A_z$ and $B_z$ are fixed and not equal. As far as I am concerned, if $X$ is the vector from point $A$ to the origin and $Y$ is the vector from $A$ to $B$, $X$ and $Y$ lengths are dependent due to their common starting point $A$. Is there any case where the dependecy can me minimized so as to set $E[XY]$ almost equal to $E[X]E[Y]\;?$[image]

Comment: There are 2 simple ways to verify the approximate equality : take $R$ very small or (an equivalent way), keep $R$ fixed but impose $A_z$ and $B_z$ very large and very different one from the other... Otherwise, I don't see...

Comment: When I set Az=0 and Bz=100 (keeping R fixed) indeed the approximation holds in my experiments. Can you please explain me why this is happening? Or suggest me something to study:)

Comment: Yes, and we can justify it ; in this case, if $R=1$ for example, the length of $AB$ is approximately $X \approx 100$ (i.e., a constant) (think that vector $\vec{AB}$ varies in a very tall and thin cylinder) and you can "expel" a constant from $E$, i.e., $E(XY)=X E(Y)=E(X)E(Y)$ (the last equation being due to the fact that the mean of a constant is this constant). The conclusion is that you will be in the condition of $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$ if one among the random variable $X,Y$ is (approximately) constant.

Comment: Ooooh I see!! It indeed makes sense. Is there a way though of proving it but not experimentally? For instance, given R and Az, what should be at least the value of Bz in order for the approximation to hold?

Comment: An answer could be : take $B_z$ at least 2 orders of magnitude (i.e., $ \times 100$) larger than $A_z$ **and** $R$.

Comment: Thank you so much!:)